# Bulk 'find and replace' function for multiple lines in Notepad++ or Programmer's Notepad?

Tags: text, replace, find, notepad++, bulk

I have a file with thousands of code lines where I need to first find a file name (text between `<path>./THIS-TEXT.rom</path>`), copy that text, and then replace the very following line (text between `<name>this-one-replaced</name>`) with that text. Then move on until the next sequence is found.

I've been manually doing this before realizing it will likely take me 8 hours of manually doing this to complete my project. I figure there must be some easier way to do this. Below is an example of the two code blocks in succession. Mind you that it's just two out of several thousand in succession.

```
<game id="494">
    <path>./The Legend of Zelda.rom</path>
    <name>legend of zelda, the (en,eu,it)</name>
    <genre>Miscellaneous</genre>
</game>
<game id="954">
    <path>./Final Fantasy.rom</path>
    <name>final fantasy (usa, europe)</name>
    <genre>Miscellaneous</genre>
</game>
```

Basically, I need to figure out how to take text between `<path>./` and 
`.rom</path>`, and replace the next line with it between `<name>` and `</name>` to look like this as it moves down the file for the next occurrence.

```
<game id="494">
    <path>./The Legend of Zelda.rom</path>
    <name>The Legend of Zelda</name>
    <genre>Miscellaneous</genre>
</game>
<game id="954">
    <path>./Final Fantasy.rom</path>
    <name>Final Fantasy</name>
    <genre>Miscellaneous</genre>
</game>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Notepad++ this can be done with a simple regular expression. Search for:

```
^(\h*<path>\./)([^<>\r\n]+)(\.rom</path>\h*[\r\n]+\h*<name>)[^<>\r\n]*(</name>)
```

and replace it with

```
\1\2\3\2\4
```

**Explanation:**

`^(\h*<path>\./)` Gets the opening path text and saves it in capture group `\1`.

`([^<>\r\n]+)` Gets the wanted file name text from the path line, saving it to `\2`.

`(\.rom</path>` Gets the remainder of the path line.

`\h*[\r\n]+\h*<name>)` Gets the line break and the whitespace and the start of the name line. This text and the remainder of the path line are saved to `\3`.

`[^<>\r\n]*` Gets the unwanted part of the name line and does not save it.

`(</name>)` Gets the final part of the name line and saves it to `\4`.

Reassembly. The `\1\2\3` makes the path line and the start of the name line. The next `\2` replaces the unwanted name line text with the wanted part of the file name. The final `\4` completes the new name line.

Of course, "Regular expression" must be selected in the replace window of Notepad++.